# Magento - How to add country column in Orders grid filter?

Tags: magento

I tried:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $collection->oinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
```

but results are blank.
Please Help me add country column in Orders grid. Thanks.

Comment: is this ` $collection->oinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');` is a typo or you really missed `j`. it should be ` $collection->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy to `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid` to   `app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid`

In the file add below code for append billing address to order grid  to `prepareCollection` function

```
$collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_address', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id',array('telephone','city','postcode','country_id' ) )->where("sales_flat_order_address.address_type =  'billing'");
```

Full code is

```
  protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());


$collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_address', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id',array('telephone','city','postcode','country_id' ) )->where("sales_flat_order_address.address_type =  'billing'");

        $this->setCollection($collection);

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

and then add the below code to _prepareColumns()

```
 $this->addColumn('country_id', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Country Id'),
            'index' => 'country_id',
            'filter_index' => 'sales_flat_order_address.country_id',
        ));
```

If want to Country list then add below code 
_prepareCollection()

```
 $this->addColumn('country_id', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Country Id'),
            'index' => 'country_id',
        'type'=> 'options',
        'options'=>$this->getAllCountry(),      
            'filter_index' => 'sales_flat_order_address.country_id',
        ));
```

And then add new function on this file

```
public function getAllCountry(){
    $options = Mage::getResourceModel('directory/country_collection')->load()->toOptionArray(); 
        $countries = array(); 
        foreach($options as $options){
             $countries[$options['value']]=$options['label']; 
            } 
    return $countries;
    }
```

More details on  http://bluehorse.in/blog/how-to-add-some-field-or-column--into-magento-order-grid-in-magento-or-customized-magento-order-grid.html

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-extend-magento-order-grid/

Comment: Thanks for reply, You're right, but it's show country id only, i want to show country name? Can u help me again?

Comment: Thanks so much, i've been finish, thanks for suggesting

Comment: $options = Mage::getResourceModel('directory/country_collection')->load()->toOptionArray();
       $countries = array();
       foreach($options as $options){
        $countries[$options['value']]=$options['label'];
       }
it's ok. :)

Answer (score 0):

Also, I would suggest you to refer below articles as well. It will definitely help you out.

https://www.mageworx.com/blog/how-to-add-column-with-filter-to-magento-2-orders-grid/
https://www.magentoexpertise.in/shipping-country-column-on-the-sales-order-grid/
https://belvg.com/blog/how-to-add-column-in-sales-order-grid-in-magento-2-1.html

In summary,

Below example created to add the country code on the sales order grid page

1. Create a UI component to add your new column (column name - ex: country_id must be same as the database table column name)

/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
File Signature
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="country_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Country Code (Ex: AU or NZ)</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

2. Add a plugin to append the additional column data to sales order grid table column

/app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
File Signature
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <plugin name="vendor_module_plugin_view_element_uicomponent_dataprovider_collectionfactory"
            type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\PluginAddDataToSalesOrdersGrid"
            sortOrder="1"
            disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

3. Create the plugin to append column data to report result collection. Anyway, you can customize the plugin query to get the required data as you need. If you would change it make sure to update the correct DB table column name in /app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml as well.

/app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/PluginAddDataToSalesOrdersGrid.php

```
<?php
/**
 * File Signature
 */

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

/**
 * Class PluginAddDataToSalesOrdersGrid
 */
class PluginAddDataToSalesOrdersGrid
{
    /**
     * Execute after the getReport function to
     * Append additional data to sales order grid
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory $subject
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection $resultCollection
     * @param $requestName
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterGetReport($subject, $resultCollection, $requestName)
    {
        if ($requestName !== 'sales_order_grid_data_source') {
            return $resultCollection;
        }
        if ($resultCollection->getMainTable() === $resultCollection->getResource()->getTable('sales_order_grid')) {
            try {
                $orderAddressTableName = $resultCollection->getResource()->getTable('sales_order_address');
                $resultCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                    ['soa' => $orderAddressTableName],
                    'soa.parent_id = main_table.entity_id AND soa.address_type = \'shipping\'',
                    ['soa.country_id']
                );
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // Not required to log and added the try catch to make sure
                // flow is not breaking while processing the report
            }
        }
        return $resultCollection;
    }
}
```

Cheers!